# Is there any way to tell which property does a value come from?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know its a long stretch but... just had to try.

For example if I made a DateTime control with a SelectedDate property, if in the server-side code it is being set to Person.DateOfBirth, in the DateTime control is there any way to tell that the SelectedDate came from Person.DateOfBirth?

Comment: Why do you want this functionality?

Comment: I'm dealing with an internationalized system where dates are converted to UTC right in the datetime control before going to the back-end. Recently there have been increasing instances where some dates need to be... immutable. For example, a person's date of birth, if he/she inputs 15th of June, DateTime will save it with the time component of 00:00:00 so when that gets converted to UTC (-10) it will be saved as 14/06 14:00:00 so when someone on a different timezone viewed it, it may turn to a different date.

Comment: What I've done is set these dates with a custom attribute "sticky", and currently finding a way to read this in the control to stop the datetime conversion.

As of now they are being converted back manually in the server-side code but I can see this turning into a maintenance nightmare...

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do clearly violates [Separation of Concerns Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The job of the DateTime control is displaying date time and allowing user to change it. It should not know about where the DateTime came from.

Quite frankly I struggle to think about why one would need this functionality. Form is a fairly well understood UI paradigm. You load the form, set the form elements' values from the model, let user change values, read all the values back, validate them and update the model. What else can it possible do?

**EDIT** For this particular problem all you need to do is to create flag on your datetime control, say `ConvertToUTC`. When set to true, it will convert the time into UTC, if not, the value the user entered will stay the same. Should be nice and clean that way.

Comment: That is true... I might've strayed the wrong way due to not wanting to change the current framework

Comment: @neo: It is FAR better to change an existing framework than to create a horrid coupling between types like this. Identifying a caller and making that a dependent part of your architecture will only compound your maintenance problems, not alleviate them. `Separation of Concerns` is a saving grace, and if you can **fix** your current framework to maintain separation of concerns, you WILL improve your maintenance scenario.

Comment: Yeah that's what the current solution is at the moment, a "StickyDate" bool property on the control

Answer (score 0):

Not generally, no.

It should be possible, if one were so inclined, to examine the call stack at the time of setting the property, but that would be pretty poor form, and indicative of an underlying issue. I say you try and solve your problem in another way. What result are you looking for? What do you want to do?

Comment: I've just explained the scenario in the question's comments.
And no I wouldn't resort to call stacks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to agree with silky if you want to do this generally.

However, if just want to do it for a specific class, or in this case a control, you could of course create your own control, inherit from whatever control you wanted, and then override the property and modify the setter to save some extra info.

But I'm guessing you want to do this generally....

Comment: I've done exactly that, overriding the property in a custom control but the value in the setter shows no indication what object it belonged to, by the time its in the setter its just a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but just a thought.

If the selected date value set and get is accessed through a Func<> delegate and you will set the parameter to whatever the target is. From the Func<> object, you should then be able to ask for the Method and Target.  I haven't tried this myself, so will be great to hear your thought on this if you did try it.

Just to add to this with a possible example:

```
Func<DateTime> _selectedDate = person.GetDateOfBirth();
```

So later on you can ask for the source such as

```
if (_selectedDate.Target.GetType() == typeof(Person))
   doSomething()
```

Comment: That sounds like it includes either changing the selected date object type or adding a new property to the control... but thanks! I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to get the setter client-side. You could set the "rel" attribute to the setter, and then get the "rel" attribute client-side (e.g. jQuery).

```
// server-side.    
DateTimeControl.Attributes["rel"] = "Person.DateOfBirth";

// client-side (jQuery).
if $('#DateTimeControl').attr('rel') == 'Person.DateOfBirth' {
    // logic here.
}
```

Let me know if I need to elaborate -thank you.